# css table inner border only

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

How to create a table with no outer border but inner borders only. Something like [this one](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) (See bottom right in the page). I know that I can create it manually like they did, I mean to give a class to each td but isn't out there a better way to realize this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they didn't do it that way, it's done in a nice way! :)

This removes the right border from the cells:

```
.sidebar-stats td:last-child, .sidebar-stats th:last-child {
    border-right: 0 none;
}
```

(In the same way you can remove the bottom-border for the last row. You can use Firebug to analyse their CSS, helps a lot!)

Comment: @Shaokan: `:last-child` only works in IE9 and greater. It's worth pointing out that sites don't have to look the same in every browser. This is only a minor cosmetic issue, so it's fine to let it slide for IE7/8.

Comment: well, yeah I agree. I prefer using -webkit-border-radius instead of struggling with divs and images to create rounded corners for instance, but still I just asked to be sure :) Thanks!

Comment: @Shaokan - if you want to support IE7/8, you can switch the side of the borders, because IE7/8 may not work with `last-child`, but they do support `first-child`, so this technique can be used. Oh, and re your other comment, for CSS-compatible rounded corners in IE7/8, see [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that'll work in all browsers, but requires you to add a CSS class to the furthest right and bottom `<td>`'s in your table (vs having to give a class to each `<td>`)

```
<table>
    <tr><td class="inner">text</td><td class="inner right">text</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="inner bottom">text</td><td class="inner bottom right">text</td></tr>
</table>

.inner {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;    
}

.right {
    border-right: 0;   
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HS4nQ/3/

Comment: Thanks dude for your efforts :) Actually, that's what I mentioned while asking the question, that if there is another way to do so rather than this way :) Still, +1 for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

You can style the `td` elements to have borders, and then giver your table `border:0`, an make sure to add `border-collapse:collapse` to the table as well. It should look like this in the end:

```
table {
border:0;
border-collapse:collapse;
}

td {
border:1px gray solid;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the :first-child variation:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Z7R9/

```
table.mytable > * > tr > th,
table.mytable > * > tr > td {
  border-left: 10px solid red;
  border-top:  10px solid red;
}

table.mytable > * > tr > th,
table.mytable > * > tr > td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

table.mytable > *:first-child > tr:first-child > th,
table.mytable > *:first-child > tr:first-child > td {
  border-top: none;
}
```